# Convert ArcGIS cartographic representations to KML?

Tags: kml, arcgis

I am using cartographic representations to symbolize roads such that both directions are visible. I need to convert this to KML. However, the Layer to KML tool from ArcToolbox creates an empty file. Is it possible to convert cartographic representations to KML? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Layer to KML should work just fine.  I have only had issues with it when there are underlying coordinate system problems.  Does it give you any particular error?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options.

1. Layer to KML - this should work and is moderately easy
2. Arc2Earth - You can get a limited community edition for free
3. Excel based tools - get your data in a spreadsheet and upload to any [online](http://www.earthpoint.us/ExcelToKml.aspx) tool or [download](http://www.ehow.com/how_6808709_convert-ms-excel-kml.html) an [offline](http://www.ehow.com/how_8560245_convert-csv-kml.html) based implementation
4. Google Fusion Tables - requires spreadsheet type data
5. Python - Either as string templates or using something like [simplekml](http://code.google.com/p/simplekml/)